# change superuser password in django

Tags: django, change-password, superuser

I tried to change my admin password but I have an error while running `user = User.objects.get(username='normaluser')` [image: invalid input][image: shell error]

Comment: You'll have to import the user model from `core` app

Comment: @BrianDestura If I use `from django.contrib.core.models import User` it show this error **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.core'**

Comment: Did you change your user model using `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? if so, you need to use that app's user model.

Comment: @BrianDestura No I don't, how can I use this command `AUTH_USER_MODEL` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```py
python manage.py changepassword <user_name>
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)

> manage.py changepassword *username* offers a method of changing a user’s password from the command line.

Comment: When I run `python manage.py changepassword <admin>` I have this error **The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

Comment: Remove the `<` and `>`

Comment: Yeah it was meant to be a placeholder... my bad (this is provided that the admin's name is `admin`)

Comment: I tried without `<` and `>` and this is the error : **CommandError: user 'admin' does not exist**

Comment: What is your superuser's username?